# How do you properly close a COMObject in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I run this code in Jupyter Notebook to access a Microsoft Project file, it runs **the first time** without error.

```
import win32com.client

pjApp = win32com.client.Dispatch('MSProject.Application')
pjApp.FileOpen('X:/test.mpp')

pjApp.FileClose()
pjApp.Quit()   # I also tried pjApp.Application.Quit()
pjApp = None
del pjApp
```

Then if I run it again without restarting the kernel (or wrap it in a loop to get a few runs in), it throws:

```
AttributeError: MSPRoject.Application.FileOpen
```

I'm thinking that I need to better clean up the first run, but I'm not sure how.

I've even tried adding this code to kill the process I started, but no luck.

```
for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    if proc.name() == "WINPROJ.EXE":
        proc.kill()
```

This is my version: **Python 3.6.4 :: Anaconda, Inc.** Any ideas?

Comment: Try `pjApp.FileClose()` if that's available

Comment: @ThomasWeller Darn, just tried it and got the same result. I'll update the question with this new attempt

Comment: Have you tried setting `pjApp = None` prior to deleting it? Sometimes this can be used by the API to do some cleanup.

Comment: Or `pjApp.Application.Quit()`?

Comment: @DanielF I just tried various combinations of both now, and still nothing.